# How can I do if I want to put the diagram in the center of the document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-uml

Here's my LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \title{Diagrama Casos de uso en \LaTeX{} - Devoluci\'on a proveedores}
    \author{Esteban Vera Valdez}
    \maketitle

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlsystem}[fill=red!10]{Sistema}
        \setcounter{tikzumlUseCaseNum}{0}
        \umlusecase{Solicitar inventario}
        \umlusecase[x=2.3, y=-1.5, width=2.7cm]{Solicitar devoluci\'on}
        \umlusecase[x=2.3, y=-3, width=2.3cm]{Generar documentaci\'on}
        \umlusecase[y=-4.5]{Generar inventario}
        \umlusecase[x=7.2, fill=green!20]{Solicitar docuentaci\'on}
        \umlusecase[x=7.2, y=-1.5, fill=green!20]{Realiza la devoluci\'on}
        \umlusecase[x=6.5, y=-3.8]{Recibe fac. y pedido}
        \umlusecase[x=5.8, y=-5]{Registra datos}
        \umlusecase[y=-6]{Almacenar datos}
        \umlusecase[y=-7.5]{Almacenar prod.}
        \umlusecase[y=-9]{Actualizar inventario}
        \umlusecase[x=5.8, y=-7.4, width=2.6cm]{Lista productos defectuosos}
        \end{umlsystem}

        \umlactor[x=-4, y=-3.4]{Usuario}
        \umlactor[x=-4, y=-7.5]{Sistema}
        \umlactor[x=12,y=-1.5]{Proveedor}

        \umlinherit{Usuario}{Sistema}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-1}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-2}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-3}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-7}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-8}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-4}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-9}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-10}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-11}
        \umlassoc{Proveedor}{usecase-5}
        \umlassoc{Proveedor}{usecase-6}
        \umlinherit{usecase-1}{usecase-4}
        \umlinherit{usecase-2}{usecase-5}
        \umlinherit{usecase-6}{usecase-7}
        \umlVHextend{usecase-8}{usecase-9}
        \umlinclude[name=incl]{usecase-4}{usecase-12}

        \umlnote[x=4.3, y=-9]{incl-1}{Muestra info del proveedor}

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}        
\end{document}
```

[image: My Diagram]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the package `tikz-uml` proprietary? If not, can it be downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: @Mico Yes, see the tag description (the long one) for [tag:tikz-uml].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your picture is wider than `\textwidth`. You could use

```
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}
```

to center the whole picture relatively to the text body.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}% loads also tikz, graphicx, xcolor,...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}% only for the example to show the page layout

\begin{document}
  \title{Diagrama Casos de uso en \LaTeX{} - Devoluci\'on a proveedores}
  \author{Esteban Vera Valdez}
  \maketitle

  \begin{center}
    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlsystem}[fill=red!10]{Sistema}
          \setcounter{tikzumlUseCaseNum}{0}
          \umlusecase{Solicitar inventario}
          \umlusecase[x=2.3, y=-1.5, width=2.7cm]{Solicitar devoluci\'on}
          \umlusecase[x=2.3, y=-3, width=2.3cm]{Generar documentaci\'on}
          \umlusecase[y=-4.5]{Generar inventario}
          \umlusecase[x=7.2, fill=green!20]{Solicitar docuentaci\'on}
          \umlusecase[x=7.2, y=-1.5, fill=green!20]{Realiza la devoluci\'on}
          \umlusecase[x=6.5, y=-3.8]{Recibe fac. y pedido}
          \umlusecase[x=5.8, y=-5]{Registra datos}
          \umlusecase[y=-6]{Almacenar datos}
          \umlusecase[y=-7.5]{Almacenar prod.}
          \umlusecase[y=-9]{Actualizar inventario}
          \umlusecase[x=5.8, y=-7.4, width=2.6cm]{Lista productos defectuosos}
        \end{umlsystem}
        %
        \umlactor[x=-4, y=-3.4]{Usuario}
        \umlactor[x=-4, y=-7.5]{Sistema}
        \umlactor[x=12,y=-1.5]{Proveedor}
        %
        \umlinherit{Usuario}{Sistema}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-1}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-2}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-3}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-7}
        \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-8}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-4}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-9}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-10}
        \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-11}
        \umlassoc{Proveedor}{usecase-5}
        \umlassoc{Proveedor}{usecase-6}
        \umlinherit{usecase-1}{usecase-4}
        \umlinherit{usecase-2}{usecase-5}
        \umlinherit{usecase-6}{usecase-7}
        \umlVHextend{usecase-8}{usecase-9}
        \umlinclude[name=incl]{usecase-4}{usecase-12}
        %
        \umlnote[x=4.3, y=-9]{incl-1}{Muestra info del proveedor}
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

If only the red box should be centered, you can add a `scope` for the additions with option `overlay`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}% loads also tikz, graphicx, xcolor,...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}% only for the example to show the page layout

\begin{document}
  \title{Diagrama Casos de uso en \LaTeX{} - Devoluci\'on a proveedores}
  \author{Esteban Vera Valdez}
  \maketitle

  \begin{center}
    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlsystem}[fill=red!10]{Sistema}
          \setcounter{tikzumlUseCaseNum}{0}
          \umlusecase{Solicitar inventario}
          \umlusecase[x=2.3, y=-1.5, width=2.7cm]{Solicitar devoluci\'on}
          \umlusecase[x=2.3, y=-3, width=2.3cm]{Generar documentaci\'on}
          \umlusecase[y=-4.5]{Generar inventario}
          \umlusecase[x=7.2, fill=green!20]{Solicitar docuentaci\'on}
          \umlusecase[x=7.2, y=-1.5, fill=green!20]{Realiza la devoluci\'on}
          \umlusecase[x=6.5, y=-3.8]{Recibe fac. y pedido}
          \umlusecase[x=5.8, y=-5]{Registra datos}
          \umlusecase[y=-6]{Almacenar datos}
          \umlusecase[y=-7.5]{Almacenar prod.}
          \umlusecase[y=-9]{Actualizar inventario}
          \umlusecase[x=5.8, y=-7.4, width=2.6cm]{Lista productos defectuosos}
        \end{umlsystem}
        \begin{scope}[overlay]
          \umlactor[x=-4, y=-3.4]{Usuario}
          \umlactor[x=-4, y=-7.5]{Sistema}
          \umlactor[x=12,y=-1.5]{Proveedor}
          %
          \umlinherit{Usuario}{Sistema}
          \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-1}
          \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-2}
          \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-3}
          \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-7}
          \umlassoc{Usuario}{usecase-8}
          \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-4}
          \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-9}
          \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-10}
          \umlassoc{Sistema}{usecase-11}
          \umlassoc{Proveedor}{usecase-5}
          \umlassoc{Proveedor}{usecase-6}
          \umlinherit{usecase-1}{usecase-4}
          \umlinherit{usecase-2}{usecase-5}
          \umlinherit{usecase-6}{usecase-7}
          \umlVHextend{usecase-8}{usecase-9}
          \umlinclude[name=incl]{usecase-4}{usecase-12}
          %
          \umlnote[x=4.3, y=-9]{incl-1}{Muestra info del proveedor}
        \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```